# C# show data from database in label

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I've got a program which is linked to a Microsoft Access database and what I want to do is to display data from a data column, for example, `customerName` from the table `customerDetails` into a label. The drag and drop feature from the data sources panel puts the data into text boxes by default however, I want mine in labels. I've looked around but I couldn't find anything directly referencing how to put data into different controls like labels so any help is appreciated!

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to change the default control type for your fields in Data Sources window. Since you are already using that method, simply go to Data Sources window, expand your table and select required field(s). Then select a different control type (Label in your case) from the list.

Comment: Ahh, that seems so simple and I don't know why I didn't realize this beforehand. This does the trick perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Spend some time learning exactly what magic is performed by the Data Sources window. Data Binding is a blessing, but only when you know how to use it.